# Joining events into a single row

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have some events that capture the times when different jobs start or end. Here are two events that capture the start and end times of a job-

```
[
  {
    "appName": "a1",
    "eventName": "START",
    "eventTime": "t1"
  },
  {
    "appName": "a1",
    "eventName": "END",
    "eventTime": "t2"
  },
  {
    "appName": "a1",
    "eventName": "START",
    "eventTime": "t3"
  },
  {
    "appName": "a2",
    "eventName": "START",
    "eventTime": "t4"
}
    
]
```

I am looking to visualize this information in a table showing the latest start and end times of each application, something like this -

```
--AppName--Last Start Time--Last End Time--
--a1--t3--t2--
--a2--t4--null--
```

The above table is assuming t3 comes after t1. How do i get to this ? I am able to extract the latest events for each into separate rows with this -
`stats latest(eventTime) by appName, eventName` but need them to be combined into one single tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create separate fields for start and end times, then use `stats` to get the latest for each.

```
| eval start_time=if(eventName="START", eventTime, null())
| eval end_time=if(eventName="END", eventTime, null())
| stats latest(start_time) as last_start, latest(end_time) as last_end by appName
```

XXX Note that for the `latest` function to work properly, eventTime must be in epoch format.  If it isn't, use the `strptime` function in a `eval` to convert it. XXX (Disregard this last part.)

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but have a follow up question on your coment regarding the format of eventTime. I thought the latest() function uses the `_time` field so the format of the fields within the event should not matter, is that not correct ? Even in my use case, i am able to get this to work with the eventTime being in ISO format.

Comment: That it works for you as-is means my comment is bogus.  Thanks for the feedback.